# Qwerty not working to corresponding number keys

Tags: keyboard, keymap

My keyword is behaving in a strange manner, whenever I press <kbd>W</kbd> with 2 the keyboard does not registers 2 or @ key, but with other number keys it works simultaneously.

Similarly:

- <kbd>Q</kbd> won't work with 1,
- <kbd>W</kbd> won't work with 2,
- <kbd>E</kbd> won't work with 3,

and so on.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: @DavidPostil no

Comment: Well you should, that will tell you if the keyboard is at fault or something else...